# Which Windows 10 version to install on Intel Core2Duo E7400 2.8Ghz with 4GB RAM

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, memory, upgrade, 32-vs-64-bit

I searched but I did not find a satisfactory answer to my specific query thus putting it here.

I have an old PC Intel Core2Duo E7400 2.8GHz with 4GB RAM running a Windows 7 32bit. I want to upgrade it to Windows 10 but I am confused if I should install a 32bit or a 64bit version .

My daily usage involves financial work and mostly on excel, word, pdfs and browsing or internet applications .. I don’t use any heavy applications related to gaming, photo editing etc. I do watch YouTube, download movies or Netflix on it.

I am also planning to install an SSD. Cannot upgrade RAM more than 4GIGs due to MoBo limitations. Also no external graphic card. Currently it’s the onboard graphics card.

My Question is with SSD upgrade shall I go for 64bit Windows 10 or stick to 32 bit. I don’t want the system to work slow or lag in either of the versions. I planned for a 32bit but do not want to under utilize my SSD benefit with 4GIGs RAM but also fear that installing 64bit shouldn’t choke my processor and make it slow even with SSD and 4GIG ram. Also no external graphics’s shouldn’t be a problem for a 64bit. I have plans to add external graphics at later point of time.

Please provide my best solution/suggestion.

PS: I am no engineer and don’t understand much technical language.

Comment: The requirements are the same for all editions of Windows except between 32-bit and 64-bit. The requirements for Windows 10 32-bit and Windows 10 64-bit are documented on Microsoft’s website. Due to the fact your machine barely meets the requirements for Windows 10 it doesn’t really matter which edition you install.

Answer (score 0):

If anything, the 32-bit, but I would really not try to put Win10 on a machine that old.
The problems only start with the CPU architecture, but your GPU may have no drivers at all for Win10, if it's of similar age. In dog's years or computer years, that machine is well past retirement age.

If you do attempt it, I would heartily recommend removing your current drive, & installing to a completely new drive. See if it works at all. If not you can swap back.

Comment: 32bit versions work just fine with 4gb, unless you install memory hungry apps.

Answer (score 0):

It makes little difference. 32 bit may be marginally batter because it is more efficient in use of RAM. 64 bit is compatible with more software. From what I've read, putting Windows 10 on this system can be an ordeal because the CPU is not well supported on Windows 10.

I think that spending any money on that system (eg even a cheap external gpu) is a waste. Indeed, if the machine is going to spend a significant amount of time turned on, its probably better to upgrade/replace it then use it as the electricity savings alone could offset the cost of the replacement.